# Notice: Undefined index: message error

Tags: php

I am trying to learn php coding and it's now hitting a snag as I keep getting an error:

> Error: Notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\kubebook\index.php on line 12

Source Code:

```
if ($_GET['msg'] == 1)  {

echo "You have successfully registered.";

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that message when you attempt to reference an index or variable that isn't defined. In this case, you aren't passing a `yourscript.php?msg=123` param to the script, so `$_GET['msg']` doesn't exist. First check if it is set before looking at value

```
if (isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 1)  {

echo "You have successfully registered.";

}
```

Comment: after doing that part works now i am getting Notice: Undefined index: password1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\kubebook\register.php on line 19
You did not submit a password.
This username is already registered
This email is already registered
You entered two different passwords

Comment: source code: if ($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) { array_push($errors, 'You entered two different passwords'); }

Comment: @user3421962 They showed you *exactly* how to fix that in this answer